# Swift Validate Func

Tags: swift, validation

hello i am trying to create a function under the name validate,i can use the function i created but i run into problems when i want to add it to the screen. How do I get rid of the error without creating the alert variable I created in the function on the main page?

```
func validation(title:String,message:String,uiAlertActionTitle:String){
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
    alert.addAction( UIAlertAction(title: uiAlertActionTitle, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
}
```

main place

```
validation(title: "Error", message: "Mail or Password is Wrong", uiAlertActionTitle: "OK")
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You have to return the alert from the validation function and then pass it to self.present.

Comment: i don't fully understand sorry

Comment: ```func validation(title:String,message:String,uiAlertActionTitle:String) -> UIAlertController {
    //your code
    return alert
}
let alert = validation(title: "Error....
self.present(alert```

Comment: thank you you have been very helpful